# How do you specify a blkparse format specifier that also suppresses summary

Tags: linux, performance, hardware, io, optimization

When using the live mode, I do:

> blktrace -d /dev/sdc1 -o -|blkparse -f '%a %c'  -i -

I just want to limit the displayed data to 'action' and 'cpu id'.
Instead I get the summary and all the usual fields - like so:

```
root@debian:~# blktrace -d /dev/sdc1 -o -|blkparse -f '%a %c'  -i -
G 0I 0D 0C 1A 1Q 1G 1I 1  8,33   1        0     0.223885454     0  m   N cfq171SN / insert_request
  8,33   1        0     0.223889784     0  m   N cfq171SN / add_to_rr
  8,33   1        0     0.223899213     0  m   N cfq171SN / preempt
  8,33   1        0     0.223902006     0  m   N cfq112A  / slice expired t=1
  8,33   1        0     0.223905987     0  m   N cfq112A  / resid=-5320676662
  8,33   1        0     0.223911924     0  m   N / served: vt=759045757045622 min_vt=758881917045622
  8,33   1        0     0.223915765     0  m   N cfq112A  / sl_used=40000000 disp=6 charge=40000000 iops=0 sect=848
  8,33   1        0     0.223918000     0  m   N cfq112A  / del_from_rr
  8,33   1        0     0.223926591     0  m   N cfq workload slice:100000000
  8,33   1        0     0.223929175     0  m   N cfq171SN / set_active wl_class:0 wl_type:1
  8,33   1        0     0.223934203     0  m   N cfq171SN / Not idling. st->count:1
  8,33   1        0     0.223936578     0  m   N cfq171SN / dispatch_insert
  8,33   1        0     0.223940070     0  m   N cfq171SN / dispatched a request
  8,33   1        0     0.223942375     0  m   N cfq171SN / activate rq, drv=1
D 1C 1  8,33   1        0     0.225572959     0  m   N cfq171SN / complete rqnoidle 1
  8,33   1        0     0.225579035     0  m   N cfq171SN / set_sl
```

How do i turn off the summary that is auto displayed when i ctrl-c and use -f more effectively? (I also tried "%-4c") Basically I want to suppress the standard header that is being displayed and alter it's format using -f

Answer (score 0):

Add `-q` (quiet) to suppress the summary, and include a newline in your format to get each pair of values on a new line:

```
$ sudo blktrace -d /dev/sdc1 -o - | blkparse -f '%a %c\n' -q -i -
G 0
I 0
D 0
C 1
A 1
```